# When I swing the Wii remote, the game pauses

Tags: wiimote, sonic-and-the-black-knight

I have a Wii game called 'Sonic and the Black Knight' but whenever I swing the Wii remote, the game pauses! The game has quite a lot of combat skills, It's all about sword fights, so I really need this remote to work! I've tried to change the batteries of the remote and sync it, but that didn't help either. It only happens with this game, it used to be fine, but only just started this problem. is it the game or the remote?

Just to let you know, my Wii remote is fine, but my nunchuk isn't, does that affect anything?

Comment: What is the pause button? Is this button also pressed in other games when you swing it?

Comment: What sort of pausing?  Does it show the Wii Home screen?  Or does it just pause the game?

Comment: In addition to the other questions, what do you mean by saying that the nunchuck isn't fine?

Comment: reply to Mathias711. The pause button is the + button in this game, when I swing the remote, it just pauses, without me even touching the pause button.

Comment: In reply to Frank. It just pauses the game, not the home screen.

Comment: In reply to Kappei. The nunchuk has insertion problems. It doesn't seem to connect even though it is connected. I have to press it hard in order for it to work.

Comment: Here's your test, then: Play normally, and unplug your nunchuk yourself.  If it pauses just like it does when you're swinging, you know your problem.

Comment: Try a new set of batteries and clean their contacts (they also might need to be bent back again).

Answer (score 6):

If your nunchuk "isn't fine", it is very likely that the game is pausing assuming that the nunchuk was unplugged during your movements (Bad connectors on your nunchuk or wiimote may be the source of the problem).

Try with another nunchuk or wiimote if possible.

Comment: If you have someone in your neighbourhood owning a Wii, you should maybe try to connect your wiimote with his nunchuk before. Maybe it's the wiimote's connectors that are deficient and not the nunchuk's.

Comment: Well the nunchuk is quite old, and it couldn't connect with my cousin's remote either. I don't think it's my remote because it's quite new.

Answer (score -1):

I (Having the problem myself) Have found a solution buy a new wiimote The original Wii mote I got for my Wii has a bad connector on the mote so even if I don't move the mote at all it says to connect a nunchuck. So get new remotes